# List<T> BinarySearch using a String indexer

Tags: c#, .net, list, binary-search

So I have a CreditCard class that has some properties, one of which is for the card number as a String (`public string Number { get; set; }`). I'm storing the CreditCard objects in a CreditCardList class which has the variable List (`private List<CreditCard> cclist = new List<CreditCard>();`). I want to be able to retrieve a CreditCard by its card number by sorting the List first, then using the BinarySearch method on the List. I also want to do this by passing a String indexer of the number to search for into the BinarySearch method, along with a comparer if I need one.

This is what I have so far for the method to get the CreditCard matching the number, but Visual Studio 2013 gives me an error on the line: `int index = cclist.BinarySearch(cclist[input], new CreditCardComparer());` "the best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.this[int]' has some invalid arguments." I assume it's because I'm using the String indexer wrong or something.

```
public List<CreditCard> GetCardByNumber (string input)
{
    List<CreditCard> tempList = new List<CreditCard>();

    // save the current unsorted list to a temporary list to revert back to after sorting
    List<CreditCard> originalList = new List<CreditCard>(cclist.Capacity);

    for (int i = 0; i < cclist.Capacity; i++)
    {
        originalList[i] = cclist[i];
    }

    // begin sorting for binary search of card number
    cclist.Sort();

    int index = cclist.BinarySearch(cclist[input], new CreditCardComparer());

    if (index < 0)
    {
        tempList.Add(cclist[input]);
    }

    // revert back to the original unsorted list
    for (int i = 0; i < originalList.Capacity; i++)
    {
        cclist[i] = originalList[i];
    }

    // return the found credit card matching the specified number
    return tempList;
}// end GetCardByNumber (string input)
```

Here are my int and string indexers:

```
public CreditCard this[int i]
{
    get
    {
        if (i < 0 || i >= cclist.Count)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index " + i + " does not exist");
        }

        return cclist[i];
    }
    set
    {
        if (i < 0 || i >= cclist.Count)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index " + i + " does not exist");
        }

        cclist[i] = value;
        saveNeeded = true;
    }
}// end CreditCard this[int i]

public CreditCard this[string input]
{
    get
    {
        foreach (CreditCard cc in cclist)
        {
            if (cc.Number == input)
            {
                return cc;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}// end CreditCard this[string number]
```

And here is my comparer class:

```
public class CreditCardComparer : IComparer<CreditCard>
{
    public override int Compare(CreditCard x, CreditCard y)
    {
        return x.Number.CompareTo(y.Number);
    }
}// end CreditCardComparer : IComparer<CreditCard>
```

And lastly, here are the necessities for my list sorting and what not...

```
class CreditCard : IEquatable<CreditCard>, IComparable<CreditCard>
{
    public bool Equals (CreditCard other)
    {
        if (this.Number == other.Number)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }// end Equals(CreditCard other)

    public int CompareTo(CreditCard other)
    {
        return Number.CompareTo(other.Number);
    }// end CompareTo(CreditCard other)
}
```

Is it truly possible to do what I'm attempting, i.e. sending a string indexer that returns a CreditCard object based on a string into a BinarySearch method of List?

Also, I can provide any more code if necessary, but I felt like this was a little much to begin with.

Comment: You can solve all your issues by **not storing** Credit card information to begin with, I am not sure if that is legally allowed.

Comment: It's just a sample exercise for school. No real information is involved here. :)

Comment: This seems wildly over-engineered. Must be  school project.

Comment: Yes, I feel there may be much easier ways to go about this problem; however, the assignment requires it to be done this way with a string indexer, binary search, etc...

Comment: Are you sure the assignment doesn't want you to implement a string indexer by using BinarySearch?

Comment: Um..possibly. It says "Retrieve the CreditCard with a specified number if it exists using the BinarySearch method in List<T> in the implementation of a String indexer." Would you mind explaining what the difference is?

Comment: A sort and binary search is worst case O(n^2) + O(log n) whereas enumerating the list is just worst case O(n).  I'd just enumerate the list looking for your value.

Comment: This may be a bit more of a meta question, but I thought that all school projects were frowned upon on SO? Or is that just to weed out really poorly worded questions that ask for the entire answer instead of a specific question like this one?

Comment: From the FAQ: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things amiss in your `GetCardByNumber` method. First is the method returns an entire list instead of a single CreditCard, which goes against the method name. Second, the binary search is not even needed since you do the searching in the string indexer first:

```
public CreditCard this[string input]
{
    get
    {
        foreach (CreditCard cc in cclist)
        {
            if (cc.Number == input)
            {
                return cc;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

By this point, you've already found the CreditCard with the information you need, so why search for it again in a BinarySearch? Thirdly, as was covered in landoncz's answer, you can't use a string as an index for a `List<T>`. What you probably intended to use was the `CreditCardList` instead of the `List<CreditCard>`

```
CreditCardList creditCardList = new CreditCardList();
creditCardList["1234"]; //correct

List<CreditCard> cclist = new List<CreditCard>();
cclist["1234"]; //incorrect. This is where your error is coming from.
```

If you're trying to access the indexer property inside of the class that implements it (which I'm assuming you are trying to do in your GetCardByNumber method), just use `this[index]`:

```
public class CreditCardList
{
    public CreditCard this[string s] { /*Implementation*/ }

    public CreditCard GetCard(string s)
    {
        return this[s]; // right here!
    }
}
```

---

Now... according to your comment, "`Retrieve the CreditCard with a specified number if it exists using the BinarySearch method in List<T> in the implementation of a String indexer.`", it seems to me that the assignment wants you doing something along these lines. (a thing to note is that I'm not sure of your entire implementation of the CreditCard class, so please excuse the naive instantiation in the following code)

```
public class CreditCardList
{
    private List<CreditCard> cclist = new List<CreditCard>();

    public CreditCardList()
    {
        //For the sake of an example, let's magically populate the list.
        MagicallyPopulateAList(cclist);
    }

    public CreditCard this[string s] /* In the implementation of a String indexer... */
    {
        get
        {
            CreditCard ccToSearchFor = new CreditCard() { Number = value };
            cclist.Sort();

            /* ...use the BinarySearch method... */
            int index = cclist.BinarySearch(ccToSearchFor);

            if (index >= 0)
                return cclist[index]; /* ...to retrieve a CreditCard. */
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("Credit Card Number not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it would work, though sorting the entire list on every lookup is a bit excessive. It would be better to maintain the list in sorted order as elements are added to it. `BinarySearch` can help with that, and there's even an example in the MSDN docs for the method.

Comment: Your answer cleared up a lot for me, but I have one more problem now. In my separate driver class (all I/O is in this) I'm trying to display the card matching the provided number. I got this to work just fine using the int indexer: "Console.WriteLine(cclist[n].ToString());" and it displays it correctly given a proper index of the list. The problem comes with doing the same thing, but with the string indexer: "Console.WriteLine(cclist[input].ToString())" throws an exception that the index was out of range. I implemented the string indexer like you mentioned above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @BrianReischl True true. This is a real "bare bones" approach just to get the point across, but it definitely wouldn't hurt to keep the idea of an always sorted list in mind.

Comment: @user48743 Since it's tough to pinpoint a problem without seeing the entirety of your code, could you try stepping through your code in the debugger when using your string indexer? When using a BinarySearch like above, it shouldn't be trying to access an index that doesn't exist, so color me surprised that it would throw an IndexOutOfRangeException.

Comment: @IchabodClay I found my mistake. Within the string indexer I had set up a for loop to save the unsorted list to a temporary list so that I could revert it back, and it was messing with it somehow. All is well now!

Comment: @user48743 Happy to be of service!

Answer (score 1):

A `System.Collections.Generic.List` uses an `int` as the indexer property, it does not let you use a string.

If you want to use a string as your indexer (primary key), you should probably use a `Dictionary<string,CreditCard>` instead.

Comment: The project assignment requires me to use List<T>. In fact, we haven't even covered a Dictionary class yet.

Comment: I would remove the int indexer in that case then

Comment: I have to use the int indexer in other parts of the program, but I didn't feel like posting them. The assignment says to "retrieve the CreditCard with a specified number if it exists using the BinarySearch method in List<T> in the implementation of a String indexer." But do you know how would I implement the String indexer using the BinarySearch method?